# Default value for input with simple_form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, erb, simple-form

**im trying to do default value for input**

works ok:

```
<%= f.input_field :quantity, default: '1' %>
```

but i need f.input not f.input_field

```
<%= f.input :quantity %>
```

- im trying it with standard html value - but after unsucessfull validation quantity is overriden by 1 - undesired

  ```
  <%= f.input :quantity, input_html: {value: '1'} %>
  ```
- when i remove value and validation is unsucessfull quantity is populated - everything is ok

  ```
  <%= f.input :quantity %>
  ```

**how to solve this ? 
is there any alternative like in f.input_field - :default ?
or there is any other solution with value ?**

Answer (score 160, accepted):

You can try with something like this:

```
<%= f.input :quantity, input_html: {value: f.object.quantity || '1'} %>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `selected` option of simple_form:

```
<%= f.input :quantity, selected: f.object.quantity || '1' %>
```

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
= f.input : quantity, input_html: { value: (f.object.quantity.present?) ? f.object.quantity : '1' }
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question...but, none of provided answers seem acceptable to me.  The best way to do this is to set the value in the controllers new action.

```
 def new
   WizBang.new(quantity: 1)
```

This will assign the objects quantity key to value 1 in the new action.  The edit action should rely on the object's persisted value, or a params value if validation failed and the form reloaded.  The other answers will force the quantity to 1 on edit, even if the user initially saved nil (if you allow nil).  Not ok.  I would not allow nil, but would include a 0 option in the quantity field.

```
f.input :quantity, collection (0..100)
```

much cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
<%= f.input :quantity, value: f.object.quantity || '1' %>
```

Nowadays, leaving off the `input_html` key.

Comment: That doesn't appear to be correct. Even in the latest version of the `simple_form` gem (2024-01-02, v5.3.0), the README specifies the value is set by adding `input_html: { value: 'mystring' }`. Does this work for you? I'm interested to know if you somehow configured simple_form to accept `value` at the top argument level.

Answer (score 0):

Now sure how a duplicate Question's answers get referenced, but I am sharing an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60891989/7573223) I just left on a question I flagged as a duplicate.

Here is a summary for this question:

```
 # simple_form input
 f.input :quantity, input_html: {value: f.object.quantity || '1'}
```

can become:

```
 # simple_form input
 = f.input :quantity, input_html: { value: f.object.quantity_with_default }

 # Model with date_start attribute
 class Obj
   def quantity_with_default
     # based on your model, you may need this instead: try(:quantity) || '1' 
     quantity || '1' 
   end
 end
```

This leaves the management of the data and its defaults in the controller instead of sprinkled throughout the HTML