# How to set simple_form input default value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

```
= r.input :date_start do
  = r.text_field :date_start, id: 'date_start'
```

How can I set default value for this?

Comment: duplicate question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19029129/default-value-for-input-with-simple-form solution: <%= f.input :date_start, input_html: {value: f.object.date_start || '2016/12/12'} %>

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Default value for input with simple\_form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19029129/default-value-for-input-with-simple-form)

Answer (score 2):

```
= r.input :date_start, as: :string, input_html: {value: '01/01/2015', id: 'date_start'}
```

Answer (score 1):

use this code:

```
= r.input :date_start, as: :string, input_html: {id: 'date_start',value: '07/02/2015'}
```

Comment: What's the difference between this answer and gmrash's?

Answer (score 0):

Use of Safe Navigation or `&.` explained in this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54071354/7573223) to another question, is an option here; especially when chained with the `||` operator.

Looking at the [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49065293/7573223) from [Kiry Meas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5626972/kiry-meas)

Note: I am using `Time.now` instead of `Time.new`, as I feel it is more readable, and better conveys the intent of the default value.  If you want to see the a conversation or benchmarks on now vs new, I recommend this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26719216/7573223). There is also a good explanation for why you may want to use `Time.current` instead, in this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12748804/7573223) )

```
input_html: { value: (f.object.date_start.present?) ? f.object.date_start : Time.now }
```

Same as this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19029403/7573223) to a duplicate question without explanation, the above can be rewritten as:

```
input_html: { value: f.object&.date_start || Time.now }
```

This provides the existing value if present and nil if it is not.  When paired with the `||` operator, the logic looks for the first 'truthy' response.  `nil` is not considered 'truthy' and the `||` will select the default value over `nil`, or `Time.now` in this case.

In the end, I feel like this is readable and less redundant answer to setting the default value for a simple form input.

```
 = f.input :date_start, input_html: { value: f.object&.date_start || Time.now }
```

And another reason for my refactor of Kiry's Answer, is because I fell that using a ternary in this case is approaching violating the principle of [Tell, Don't Ask](https://pragprog.com/articles/tell-dont-ask), as presented in example 4 from: [Tell, Don't Ask: refactoring examples](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/tell-dont-ask).

## Above answers the question directly, below suggests a refactor

An explanation of [Gavit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/242592/gavit)'s answer is to set the default in a migration for when the record is saved:

```
# migration
class AddDefaultToDateStartOfObj < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    change_column :objs, :date_start, -> { 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP' }
  end
end

# simple_form input
= f.input :date_start
```

Note: depending on your DB type the SQL might be different, but here is a good [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30993351/7573223) in regard to the nuances of this migration.

However, this does not work when the object is new and not a record in the database, yet.

I recommend the migration as well as building a method in the objects model that handles the default to the input would cleaner / more readable while following better coding principles.

```
 # simple_form input
 = f.input :date_start, input_html: { value: f.object.date_start_with_default }

 # Model with date_start attribute
 class Obj
   def date_start_with_default
     # based on your model, like in Kiry's comment to their own answer, you may need this instead:
     # try(:date_start) || Time.now 
     date_start || Time.now 
   end
 end
```

Now all of the logic for defaulting this value can be controlled / updated in a single place via the model.

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
= f.input :date_start, input_html: { value: (f.object.date_start.present?) ? f.object.date_start : Time.new }
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: i have tried this line of code: 
`= f.input :date_start, input_html: { value: f.object.date_start  || Time.new }`
but the result is empty value setting as the default value. If anyone facing the same issue as mine, the code above is working as expected.

Answer (score -2):

Specify it in the database:
t.date : date_start, :null => false, :default => 'now()'

Comment: What would `now()` represent? The time at the migration, or the time when someone's using the form?

Comment: `NOW()` is an SQL command that gives you the current time of the server.  Note: The author did not specify that they are suggesting this change in a migration instead of at the input like asked by the OP.